Chrome doesn't open Qbittorrent software with magnet link
When i click on magnet link using google chrome,a chrome popups (Open URL:Magnet link) : 
Clicking on the button "Open URL:Magnet link" doesn't run Qbittorrent software (v4.6.5).
Also i noticed that in windows 11 settings > Apps > Default apps > Choose defauls by link type, when i click on "magnet", it shows "Get an app to open this 'MAGNET' link" : 
Note that i made sure that Qbittorrent is associated with magnet links : 
I also, made sure that chrome's Protocol Handlers is enabled 
How to fix this magnet link problem so when i click on it, launchs QBittorrent software ?

In qBittorrent, disable and then re-enable those settings. Do magnet links open qbt from other browsers?

@music2myear disabling then enabling doens't fix the issue. And magnet links doesn't open qbt from other browsers (tested with firefox)

On my Server 2022 machine with working magnet URIs, the HKCR\magnet\shell\open\command key has a (Default) value of "C:\Program Files\qBittorrent\qbittorrent.exe" "%1". You might want to check that key on your machine.

@BenHutchison I found that solution on the net and checked the regedit, and found the value set at "C:\Program Files\qBittorrent\qbittorrent.exe" "%1"

The next thing I would try is running a magnet URI from the Windows Run (Win+R) dialog box to narrow down whether this is an OS or application problem.

@BenHutchison it seems like it's an OS problem. Windows dialog box didn't open Qbittorrent after pasting magnet link in it.

This is not a fix, but a workaround.
I downloaded Qbittorrent version "5.0.0beta1" from official website and the magnet Link works fine back again.

Please have a look at Can I answer my own question? and come back two days later and check as answered.

@help-info.de i didn't know the answer back then at the time when i asked the question. For now, i can't check the "Answer your own question" checkbox.
